# Die Satz Formulierung mit "indem" und "um"

Tags: sentence-structure, grammar-identification

Ich schreibe einen Aufsatz zum Thema "Tourismus". Ich will einige Vorteile des Tourismus darstellen

Hier ist, was ich geschrieben habe und irgendwie habe ich das Gefühl, dass der Satz nicht stimmt.

> Anschaffung der Arbeitsplätze ist eine andere Positiv-Entwicklung, indem um Tourismus anzuziehen, die Infrastruktur verbessert wird. Belebung des einheimischen Marktes und Produkte stehen im Zusammenhang mit Tourismus.

Meine Fragen: Passen der Konnektor **indem** und  **um** zusammen hier?
Wahrscheinlich habt Ihr schon verstanden, was ich schreiben will, kann man es irgendwie verbessern?

PS: Ich bereite mich für Telc C1 vor.

Answer (score 3):

Ja, der Nebensatz ist völlig in Ordnung. Eventuell könnte man die Kommasetzung noch verbessern: ich würde zwischen "indem" und "um" ein Komma setzen.

Du hast den erweiterten Infinitiv "um Tourismus anzuziehen" und du setzt ein Komma danach - dann solltest du auch ein Komma davor setzen.

Nebenbei: Die Formulierung "Anschaffung der Arbeitsplätze" ist etwas holperig. Ich vermute, du meinst "Schaffung von Arbeitsplätzen".

Comment: Danke erstmal. Das Komma Ding habe ich verstanden. Könntest du mir bitte sagen, was genau den Unterschied zwischen "Anschaffung der Arbeitsplätze" und "Schaffung von Arbeitsplätzen"  ist? Außer, dass "Anschaffung der Arbeitsplätze" Genitiv  ist?

Comment: Klar, 1) "Anschaffung" passt nicht zum Wort "Arbeitsplätze", denn Arbeitsplätze werden nicht angeschafft, sondern geschaffen. "Etwas anschaffen" bedeutet, dass man einen Gegenstand kauft (to procure, to buy), "etwas schaffen" bedeutet eher, das man etwas neu in Existenz bringt, das es vorher nicht gab (to create).

Comment: 2. Wenn man allgemein über neue, nicht näher bestimmte Arbeitsplätze redet, benutzt man nicht den bestimmten Artikel, (Es werden die Arbeitsplätze geschaffen), sondern den unbestimmten Artikel oder im Plural keinen Artikel (Es werden Arbeitsplätze geschaffen). Wenn man das substantivieren möchte, bekommt man das Problem, dass man "Arbeitsplätze" ohne Artikel nicht verständlich in den Genitiv setzen kann, darum benutzt man als Ersatz das "von": Schaffung von Arbeitsplätzen.

Comment: »... ist eine Entwicklung, indem ... verbessert wird« klingt für mich allerdings auch etwas schräg.

Comment: Wie paßt denn der Instrumentalsatz mit *indem* zum Hauptsatz? Mir erschließt sich das überhaupt nicht.

Comment: Die indem...um-Konstruktion an sich finde ich elegant; zugleich aber unnötig kompliziert. Ich kann mir gut vorstellen, dass auch Muttersprachler mit solidem Sprachgefühl kurz innehalten, um sicherzugehen, dass sie die Satzaussage richtig erfaßt haben. Keep it simple! Eine einfache Konstruktion zu verwenden, wenn man die Wahl hat, heisst nicht, der C1 unwürdig zu sein - ganz im Gegenteil. Dem zweiten Satz, "Belebung..." mangelt es an Artikeln. Ich würde hier jedenfalls mit "Die Belebung", allenfalls mit "Eine Belebung" starten wollen. Hinsichtlich der Produkte: Werden die auch belebt?

Comment: Wäre es nicht schöner, den Satz so umzuschreiben: „..., indem die Infrastruktur verbessert wird, um Tourismus anzuziehen“?

Answer (score 0):

I would put it as,

[Die] Schaffung von Arbeitsplätzen ist eine weitere Positiv-Entwicklung, die{Relativpron. Nominativ} die{Akkusativ-Artikel} Infrastruktur verbessert, die einheimischen Märkte mit mehr Produkten belebt, und damit/somit{wahlweise} mehr Tourismus anzieht.

P.S.:  By(=indem) not separating INDEM and UM with a komma, you'd start a confusion since INDEM is followed by an inverted sub-clause whereas UM'd start an infinite sub-clause - these two-in-one don#t go together.

Comment: Hier gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zum Originalsatz: Wenn ich die Konjunktion *um* verwende, gebe ich eine Absicht wieder. Diese Version dageben beschreibt eine Tatsache.